# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cart.forms'

Tags: django, python-3.x, cart

Python3.6
Django project.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category, Product
from cart.forms import CartAddProductForm
```

output:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cart.forms'

I already installed cart, but still have this error.

Comment: What is `cart`? How did you install it?

Comment: Did you also include `cart` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: did you added `cart` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`? show your list of the `cart` folder

Comment: Yes, I missed that. I forgot to cart to installed_apps. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error may raise because of not appending the app name to installed apps. Try to add cart to `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "cart", #or"cart.apps.CartAppConfig",

]
```